# Error while installing io octave package

Tags: package-management, software-installation, octave

I want to install the GNU Octave io package, but I keep receiving the following error in the process.

pkg install -forge io
sh: 1: make: not found

error: pkg: error running 'make' for the io package.

error: called from

```
configure_make at line 110 column 9
install at line 198 column 7
pkg at line 568 column 9
```

Comment: You've not provided your OS & release details; but your issue is likely you've not installed `build-essential`  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/build-essential etc)

Comment: @guiverc My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

octave-io package contains input/output data functions for Octave. This Octave add-on package is part of the Octave-Forge project.

To install the io Octave package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install octave-io
```

Comment: gfortran is already installed in my system.

Comment: @HassanMuhammad I replied to your comment by editing my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update, it works perfectly.